# Parse error with Haskell diagrams-builder

Tags: haskell, latex, haskell-diagrams

I'm trying to use the diagrams-builder package with LaTeX in order to generate diagrams in line. Following the tutorial [here](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/latex.html#running), I have a file called `test.tex` with the following contents:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=ps, extension=eps, outputdir=diagrams]{diagrams-latex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}[width=300,height=200]
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
dia = circle 1 
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

I created an empty directory called `diagrams` and tried to compile, only to be told that there is a parse error in what looks to be a file automatically generated by `diagrams-builder-ps`.

```
$ pdflatex --enable-write18 --shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/Users/nhalford/Library/texmf/tex/diagrams-latex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
No file test.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Opening diagrams-latex stream diagrams/test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs Error while compiling diagrams/test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
/var/folders/2g/_6mplpfn4fl338wr3cj949440000gn/T/Diagram58258-0.hs:3:20: error:
    parse error on input ‘-’



Package diagrams-latex Warning: Conversion of diagrams/test-diagrams-latex-fig1
.hs failed.


Package diagrams-latex Warning: Please convert diagrams/test-diagrams-latex-fig
1.hs manually.

(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I also get this error when attempting to run `diagrams-builder-ps` or `diagrams-builder-cairo` on the `.hs` file directly:

```
$ cd diagrams
$ ls
test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
$ diagrams-builder-ps -w 300 -h 200 test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
Error while compiling test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
/var/folders/2g/_6mplpfn4fl338wr3cj949440000gn/T/Diagram58289-0.hs:3:20: error:
    parse error on input ‘-’

$ diagrams-builder-cairo -w 300 -h 200 test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
Error while compiling test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
/var/folders/2g/_6mplpfn4fl338wr3cj949440000gn/T/Diagram58294-0.hs:3:20: error:
    parse error on input ‘-’

$ cat test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
dia = circle 1
$
```

Unfortunately the system deletes the temporary `.hs` file with the parse error immediately, so I'm unable to examine that file to see what exactly is causing this problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try suspending the process with `Ctrl+Z`. This may help you to view the temporary file.

Comment: I tried your `test.tex` but cannot reproduce the error.  Can you paste the contents of `test-diagrams-latex-fig1.hs`?

Comment: Incidentally, you probably don't want to use the `input` flag with the `ps` or `cairo` backends (it will cause the contents of the `.eps` file to be included directly into the LaTeX source which does not make sense).  It is intended for use with the `pgf` backend.  But in any case that is not what is causing your problem.

Comment: @brent-yorgey I've updated the original post accordingly. Perhaps there's a problem with my installation. I was having a lot of trouble installing it yesterday and ended up completely removing Haskell from my system and then redownloading the Haskell Platform core and installing with cabal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I just figured out what must be wrong, although I'm not sure of the best way to fix it.  The key is this line:

`/var/folders/2g/_6mplpfn4fl338wr3cj949440000gn/T/Diagram58289-0.hs:3:20: error:`

Notice that the name of the temporary file is `Diagram58289-0.hs`.  `diagrams-builder` calls `openTempFile` ([see here](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-builder/blob/master/src/Diagrams/Builder.hs#L210)) and then uses the base name of the resulting file as the name of the module.  So the contents of `Diagram58289-0.hs` must look something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Diagram58289-0 where

dia = circle 1
```

The problem is that a hyphen is not valid in a module name, hence the parse error (sure enough, it is in column 20 on line 3).

Although the [documentation for `openTempFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:openTempFile) says the created file will have a name of the form "`fooXXX.ext` where XXX is some random number", obviously that is not what is happening here.  And indeed, it looks like the [behavior of `openTempFile` changed recently](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/ad617a3edf832b5368146e0bbf0cf2780d9355e1); now it will always include a hyphen.  I'm guessing this behavior changed in `base-4.10`, so it will show up for anyone using GHC 8.2.

I have [created an issue on the `diagrams-builder` issue tracker](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-builder/issues/32) to keep track of this problem.  For now, one solution would be to downgrade to GHC 8.0, but that may not be a very attractive option.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Indeed, downgrading to GHC 8.0 has fixed the issue, although this certainly isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: Sure!  I will add a comment here if we figure out a good way to get it working again on GHC 8.2.

Comment: This is now fixed in diagrams-builder HEAD: https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-builder/commit/b44c754c15ab71d3350a6212ff73b3721b3b0e80 .  I will try to put out a new release with this bugfix soon.